# how to create regular expression for this sentence?

Tags: regex

i have following statement `{$("#aprilfoolc").val("HoliWed27");   $("#UgadHieXampp").val("ugadicome");}`.and i want  to get the string with combination.i have written following regex but it is not working.
please help!

```
(?=[\$("#]?)[\w]*(?<=[")]?)
```

Comment: Do you want `#aprilfoolc` or `aprilfoolc` ? From your code it looks like you're trying to get the first one but the question mentions the second one.

Comment: What language/tool do you use for your regular expressions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are using [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) by mistake, and you've confused lookbehind and lookahead. Try the following:

```
(?<=\$\(")\w*(?="\))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this simpler one :

```
'{$("#aprilfoolc").val("HoliWed27");}'.match(/\$\(\"#(\w+)\"[^"]*"(\w+)"/)
```

This returns

```
["$("#aprilfoolc").val("HoliWed27"", "aprilfoolc", "HoliWed27"]
```

where the strings you want are at indexes 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Also possible:

`/\("[#]?(.*?)"\)/`

```py
import re

s='{$("#aprilfoolc").val("HoliWed27");}'
f = re.findall(r'\("[#]?(.*?)"\)',s)
for m in f:
    print m
```

I don't know why, but if you want capturing of two groups simultaneously, so:

`/\("#(.*?)"\).*?\("(.*?)"\)/`

```py
import re

s='{$("#aprilfoolc").val("HoliWed27");}'
f = re.findall(r'\("#(.*?)"\).*?\("(.*?)"\)',s)
for m in f:
    print m[0],m[1]
```

In JavaScript:

```js
var s='{$("#aprilfoolc").val("HoliWed27")';
var re=/\("#(.*?)"\).*?\("(.*?)"\)/;
alert(s.match(re));
```

Answer (score 1):

This construction

```
(?=[\$*"#]?)
```

will match a *lookahead*, but only optional -- the character set is followed by a `?`. This kind of defeats the next part,

```
[\w]
```

which matches *word characters* only. So the lookahead will *never* match. Similar, this part

```
(?<=[")])
```

will also never match, because logically there can never be one of the characters `"` or `)` at the end of a string that matches `\w` only. Again, since this portion is optional (that `?` at the end again) it will simply never match.

It's a bit unclear what you are after. Strings inside double quotes, yes, but in the first one you want to skip the hash -- why? Given your input and desired output, this ought to work:

```
\w+(?=")
```